# RxJava2 "ProtocolViolationException: Disposable already set!"

Tags: android, rx-java

I'm playing with rxJava2 and getting

```
io.reactivex.exceptions.ProtocolViolationException: Disposable already set!
```

after trying to add stuff to CompositeDisposable. After running the app I'm calling loadPost() and when I'm calling loadPostFromRemoteDataStore(), the app crashes. This is the code.

```
public class CountriesPresenterImpl extends MvpBasePresenter<CountriesView> implements CountriesPresenter {

@Inject AppRepository mAppRepository;

private final CompositeDisposable disposables = new CompositeDisposable();

private DisposableObserver observer = new DisposableObserver<List<Post>>() {

    @Override
    public void onNext(List<Post> posts) {
        getView().setData(posts);
        getView().showContent();
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        getView().showError(e, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {

    }
};

@Override
public void attachView(CountriesView view) {
    super.attachView(view);
    App.getComponent().inject(this);
}

@Override
public void loadPost(boolean pullToRefresh) {
    disposables.add( mAppRepository.getPost()
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .subscribeWith(observer) );
}

@Override
public void loadPostFromRemoteDatatore(boolean pullToRefresh) {
    disposables.add( new AppRemoteDataStore().getPost()
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .subscribeWith(observer) );
}

@Override
public void detachView(boolean retainInstance) {
    super.detachView(retainInstance);
    if (!retainInstance) {
        disposables.clear();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It looks like it is because of .subscribeWith(observer). If you change to subscribe() and add it to disposables, everything is ok. I will investigate further.

Comment: FYI: a new proposal has been added to have a more meaningful error message for such cases like this. https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/pull/5301

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok,

I got the answer:

> - Like all other consumers, {@code DisposableCompletableObserver} can be subscribed only once.
> - Any subsequent attempt to subscribe it to a new source will yield an
> - {@link IllegalStateException} with message {@code "Disposable already set!"}.

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/fa58d36375ecc084b21bca299ca4780946b15dc5/src/main/java/io/reactivex/observers/DisposableCompletableObserver.java

You have create an DisposableObserver every time you use subscribeWith.

Answer (score 1):

You can't subscribe to two different observables with the same DisposableObservable instance. See the documentation [here](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/observers/DisposableObserver.html).